# Large Unwanted Space at the Bottom of Blog Posts

Tags: css, blog

I'm a bit stumped as the why there is such a large space at the bottom of the blog posts. I've tried removing the "more" tag, I've inspected the element multiple times, but just cant seem to get rid of it. Any suggestions?
http://gregtaylordesignstudio.com/sayyes/?page_id=10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's being caused by the style for `.clearfix:after`, which is doing a `clear: both;` ([Screenshot of code](http://d.pr/i/9WKt))

Adding the following to your CSS will resolve the issue:

```
.post-content.clearfix:after {
    clear: left;
}
```

[Screenshot of result](http://d.pr/i/csHi)